# Hadoop Code - Git and SVN

Tags: git, svn, hadoop

All the Apache Hadoop Code is hosted in SVN. How does Git help in Hadoop development process? It's not clear from the below article.

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GitAndHadoop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The official location for Hadoop is the Apache SVN repository; Git is
>   also supported, and useful if you want to make lots of local changes
>   -and keep those changes under some form or private or public revision
>   control.

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToContribute

Update: the official location is now the Apache Git repository.

> A lot of people use Git with Hadoop because they have their own
>   patches to make to Hadoop, and Git helps them manage it. Apache serves
>   up read-only Git versions of their source at http://git.apache.org/.
>   People cannot commit changes with Git; for that the patches need to be
>   applied to the SVN repositories.

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToContribute

These lines make it pretty clear.